# Installing DeepLearning4j fails with eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, deeplearning4j

I downloaded the entire project and import into Eclipse, but fails on this plugin:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.lewisd:lint-maven-plugin:0.0.11:check (execution: pom-lint, phase: validate)   pom.xml /dl4j-examples  line 8  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

What's the problem and how to get it compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be using m2eclipse. You don't need to "import the whole project" It's actually 6 projects total. You are better off downloading our examples where it will be managed for you. We cover this in our quick start (granted it's with intellij but the ideas are similar):
http://deeplearning4j.org/quickstart

Comment: I tweaked the POM a bit and it solved the "lint-maven-plugin" problem. However, I received a "log can not be resolved" problem. In some classes, i.e. "FitFromFeaturized", the "log.info()" is used, but "log" is not defined in the class. So it complaints this. Where is this log defined in some classes?

Comment: So wait..I mentioned the examples not deeplearning4j itself. You shouldn't be importing that. You don't need to. I'm only guessing you are doing this (you really shouldn't did I mention that?) because that will happen because of lombok. You can use maven to both obtain the sources of releases as well as for dependency management.

Comment: Yes. I git the whole dl4j projects and "mvn clean install" without problems. After I imported all the projects in Eclipse and fixed the lint plugin problems, all projects worked fine except "dl4j-cuda-specific-examples" and "dl4j-spark", in which the "log" is missing. How to fix the lombok issue in Eclipse?

Comment: @user697911can you please share how you've fixed the com.lewisd:lint-maven-plugin problem?

Comment: So for anyone looking at this...we generally shouldn't have lombok anywhere in the examples. This was fixed long ago.